# Create a Wordpress Shortcode with functions in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The shortcode I'm trying to create should return the 1 Hungarian word described below, this should change month to month. The code has been placed into functions.php and returns nothing when the shortcode is used in a page or post. Any help would be much appreciated. It does work when used as simple php and html by using `echo honapnev($honap);`.

```
    $honap = date("n");
function honapnev_shortcode( $ho ) {

  if ($ho==1) {
        return "Januári";
    }
  elseif ($ho==2) {
        return "Februári";
    }
  elseif ($ho==3) {
        return "Márciusi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==4) {
        return "Áprilisi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==5) {
        return "Májusi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==6) {
        return "Júniusi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==7) {
        return "Júliusi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==8) {
        return "Augusztusi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==9) {
        return "Szeptemberi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==10) {
        return "Októberi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==11) {
        return "Novemberi";
    }
  elseif ($ho==12) {
        return "Decemberi";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'honapnev', 'honapnev_shortcode' );
```

When I remove the line `add_shortcode( 'honapnev', 'honapnev_shortcode' );`
the shortcode in brackets appears on the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function honapnev_shortcode($atts)
{        
    switch (date("n"))
    {
        case 1:
            {
                $month="Januári";
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                $month="Februári";
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                $month="Márciusi";
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                $month="Áprilisi";
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                $month="Májusi";
                break;
            }
        case 6:
            {
                $month="Júniusi";
                break;
            }
        case 7:
            {
                $month="Júliusi";
                break;
            }
        case 8:
            {
                $month="Augusztusi";
                break;
            }
        case 9:
            {
                $month="Szeptemberi";
                break;
            }
        case 10:
            {
                $month="Októberi";
                break;
            }
        case 11:
            {
                $month="Novemberi";
                break;
            }
        case 12:
            {
                $month="Decemberi";
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                $month="Januári";
                break;
            }
    }
    return $month;
}

add_shortcode('honapnev', 'honapnev_shortcode');
```

or

```
function honapnev_shortcode($atts)
{        
   $months=array("Januári", "Februári", "Márciusi", "Áprilisi", "Májusi","Júniusi", "Júliusi", "Augusztusi","Szeptemberi", "Októberi", "Novemberi", "Decemberi");
   return $months[date("n")-1];
}

add_shortcode('honapnev', 'honapnev_shortcode');
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do with PHP, is look for the date and see wich month it is currently. So if if ($ho==1) ($ho represents the month)
If month = 1 (January) it should display the word Januári

Comment: I don't want to change the shortcode every month. It should look for the current date ` $honap = date("n");` if it equals 9 for september, it should display "Szeptemberi"

Comment: I've updated the answer. Putting [honapnev] in post/page will return month, Szeptemberi currently

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you for the great support, and feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the shortcode attributes in your function first, also, the elseif or switch statements can be replaced to get a short function.

```
function honapnev_shortcode($atts)
{
    /**
     * Get the shortcode attributes default value = 1
     */
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'ho' => 1,
    ), $atts, 'honapnev');

    $ho = intval($atts['ho']);
    /**
     * Is better use an Array in this case
     */
    $words = ['Januári', 'Februári', 'Márciusi', 'Áprilisi', 'Májusi', 'Júniusi', 'Júliusi', 'Augusztusi', 'Szeptemberi', 'Októberi', 'Novemberi', 'Decemberi'];

    return $words[$ho - 1];

}
add_shortcode('honapnev', 'honapnev_shortcode');
```

The shortcode

`[honapnev]`

`[honapnev ho="1"]`

`[honapnev ho="6"]`

`[honapnev ho="12"]`